# Can't stroke path after filling it

Tags: ios, core-graphics, drawrect

The code below nicely creates a rounded rectangle that is defined by a CGRect (rectRect).

It fills fine, but I am not getting a stroke. Any ideas why I can't see the stroke?

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 1, 1, 1, 1);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 4.0);

    float fw, fh;
    rect = rectRect;
    float ovalWidth = 12;
    float ovalHeight = 12;

    if (ovalWidth == 0 || ovalHeight == 0) {
        CGContextAddRect(ctx, rect);
        return;
    }

    CGContextTranslateCTM (ctx, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    CGContextScaleCTM (ctx, ovalWidth, ovalHeight);
    fw = CGRectGetWidth (rect) / ovalWidth;
    fh = CGRectGetHeight (rect) / ovalHeight;
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, fw, fh/2);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(ctx, fw, fh, fw/2, fh, 1);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(ctx, 0, fh, 0, fh/2, 1);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(ctx, 0, 0, fw/2, 0, 1);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(ctx, fw, 0, fw, fh/2, 1);
    CGContextClosePath(ctx);

    CGContextFillPath(ctx);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

}
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

When you paint a path, either by stroking it or by filling it, the graphics context resets its path to empty.  So after you call `CGContextFillPath`, the context doesn't have a path to stroke.

Instead of trying to fill the path and then stroke it, you can use the `CGContextDrawPath` function to do both in one call:

```
CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathFillStroke);
```

The `kCGPathFillStroke` constant tells Core Graphics to fill the path and then stroke it.

On the other hand, you could use `UIBezierPath` and `UIColor` to reduce the amount of code substantially:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.4] setFill];
    [[UIColor whiteColor] setStroke];

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rectRect cornerRadius:12];
    path.lineWidth = 4;
    [path fill];
    [path stroke];
}
```

Comment: Oh by the way, is the UIBezierPath option the high performance fix? It works perfectly of course. Or should I be looking elsewhere.

Comment: Don't worry about performance until Instruments tells you where your bottlenecks are.

Comment: I have revised my answer to avoid copying the path.

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 5** version. The important part:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
    context.move(...) // Make path
    context.addLine(...)
    ...
    context.closePath()
    context.setLineWidth(lineWidth)
    context.setStrokeColor(strokeColor!.cgColor)
    context.setFillColor(fillColor!.cgColor)
    context.drawPath(using: .fillStroke) // Fill and stroke
}
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me, I managed to have a fill color an a different border color